# Remove text generated by a tag

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website and I have made an image clickable that takes the user to the same image but the full resolution, now the problem is that it generates empty text which is taking up a line and is quite annoying.

So is there a way to fix this preferably with html and css?

Thanks in advance.

[This is the image for the problem with the intruder line highlighted, it is the  tag with 4px * 20px size.](http://i.imgur.com/vR5Gzgk.png)

and the code is as follows streamlined to the relevant bits of-course;

```
<head>
<style>
.innerBox{
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-top:0px;    
    padding-bottom:5px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.innerBox img{
    width: 320px;
    height: 180px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:0px;    
    padding-bottom:0px; 
    margin:0px;
}
.innerBox a{
    display:inline;
    font-family: Noto Sans;
    color: rgb(230,230,230);
    border-bottom: solid rgba(0,0,0,0) 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding-left:2px;
    padding-right:2px;
    padding-top:0px;    
    padding-bottom:0px; 
}</style>
</head>
<div class=innerBox>
<a href="images/xx.png" target="_blank"><img src="images/xx.png"></img></a>
<p>All the text goes here</p>
<p>and also here</p>
<p>as well as here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[see working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpjt4yx5/). I have changed the `<a>` element from `display:inline` to `display:block`. Also please note that you don't need a closing tag for `<img>`.

Comment: Glad this fixed the issue, you can do as lot with the `display` attribute to help with your positioning, the `position` attribute can also help with positioning but it was have a bigger impact to the content around it.

Comment: Also do you recommend ending the <img> with > or /> both seem to work the same, at least in chrome, Just wanted to get some input from someone who knows what they are doing.

Comment: If this has solved your issue, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: In HTML 5, you can either choose to use `<img />` or `<img>`, both will work just fine. However the correct practice is to use `<img />`.

Comment: It has, but StackOverflow tells me I need to wait another minute before accepting an answer.

Comment: okay thank you very much for solving the issue and for the input, I appreciate it.

Comment: WRT the ending slash in void elements, there is no "correct practice". You can use `<element>`, `<element/>` or `<element />` as you like, there is no difference. While on the subject of syntactical correctness however, it is an error to omit the `alt` attribute from an `img`.